# creating a other topic in rviz display plugin

Tags: ros, rviz, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
i created a new Display Plugin for Rviz but i wanted to to create an other topic to return some information.
Because i have no argv and argc arguments i cant do ros::init ... and if i just create a new ros::NodeHandle this works sometimes fine ... but i guess if nothing is displayed it stops on ros::spineOnce() is this normal or is the problem somewhere else in my code?

so the main question is what is the right way to create a new Topic in a rviz display plugin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242174/creating-a-other-topic-in-rviz-display-plugin/) by [dagdiab](https://answers.ros.org/users/27808/dagdiab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz calls `ros::init()` and will handle spinning. I think you just need to create a node handle and then create a subscriber from that node handle. You shouldn't need to do anything else.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2016-08-25**:
In fact, the [Display](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rviz/html/c++/classrviz_1_1Display.html#pro-attribs) class has 2 protected NodeHandle members already, `threaded_nh_` (non-GUI thread) and `update_nh_` (GUI thread).